# Editing element in wordpress causes multiple elements to change also?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry if this makes no sense as am only just getting to grips with WordPress and editing CSS.

I have a calendar plugin which for the most part is pretty standard.

However, I wish to make a minimum height for the elements so if there isn't much text, the format still looks better.

Following tutorials, I am able to inspect the source, make the change, and have the desired effect. My issue is, that if I find the element, it seems the custom CSS makes changes to multiple elements on the screen, I can work round most of this but it effectively breaks a clickable link (Makes it not cover the whole button).

The element part I edit is quite large but here is a chunk of it:

`.tribe-common abbr, .tribe-common acronym, .tribe-common address, .tribe-common applet, .tribe-common article,`

There's about 50, so I'm guessing my edit is covering too much or that I'm editing an attribute that more than one element inherits?

The only attribute I am setting is min-height, so unsure why this seems to make the clickable button area smaller? The button itself stays the same, but I can only click it right at the top.

The plugin I am using is a free one called events calendar. And for the most part I am able to edit the way I've described, I am just struggling to get this one to work and thought it might be the giant list that's causing it. Or should I say my lack of knowledge

Thanks

Comment: Well. I guess people will have hard time to look into your question. You need to create relevant demo or screenshots to illustrate your example. Even screenshots would be sometimes unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i get the issue you are describing correctly, but if your changes in css apply to some elements that you don't want them to apply, then you are not precise enough with your selector.

For example, the element you mentioned in your text contains many commas (","), which select all elements separated with comma. This makes your selection wider, not narrowing it down.

If you are not familiar with syntax of CSS selectors, i recommend checking out this resource:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp